# SQLcontext version alignment with spark-core

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am building my workspace in Scala-IDE for Spark-core and Dataframes. Below are the endpoints i am provided in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11  -->


<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Looks like the versions are not compatible. Which sqlContext version shall i use with spark-core-1.6.2 .

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And I would use the same scala versions in both dependencys! You specifiy in your dependencys scala 2.10 for spark core and 2.11 for spark sql.
And at the moment Spark Core 1.6.3 is available, but not Spark SQL 1.6.3. but when it is available, you should change your pom to it, because they  have released a lot of [bugfixes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12315420&version=12336854).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <scala.version>2.11.7</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
    <spark.sql.version>1.6.0</spark.sql.version>
    <spark.core.version>1.6.0</spark.core.version>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.sql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes I can understand its really difficult to get the resolve the dependency, but  need to understand the dependent object that is dependent each other

Comment: I will suggest please look into the matrix of the maven repository in the below sites: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.11/1.6.0